# Javascript dynamic content display

Tags: javascript

I am working on  a webpage requires you to input your country and city, and i want to javascript to dynamically change the contents to be displayed in the city input tag to respect to the particular country chosen how do i do this please?

Comment: What do you have so far? Where do you get your countries/cities map?

Comment: You should search about Javascript events first.

Comment: Search for Ajax select

Comment: I will list all the countries there and i want that as soon as maybe NIgeria is selected all the states in nigeria is avaliable in the city input tag

Comment: seriously? have you tried anything yet?